# Control not entering cognito authenticate function

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, amazon-cognito

For some reason, the control is not entering cognito authenticate in my API, eventhough I am providing all the values. This was working on my workspace system, but when it stopped working on a different system.
Below is the code which calls my authenticate function (The authenticate function is being called from the login function:

```js
    export class UserCAO {
    private poolData;
    private CognitoUserPool: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool;
    private pool_region: string;
    private userPool;
    private cognitoUser: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser;
    private companyID: string;
  constructor() {
        this.poolData = {
            UserPoolId: process.env.COGNITO_USER_POOL_ID,
            ClientId: process.env.COGNITO_CLIENT_ID
        }
        this.pool_region = process.env.COGNITO_POOL_REGION!;
        this.userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(this.poolData);
    }

    public async login(req: UserLoginRequest): Promise<object> {
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            console.log(`This is the req password-----> ${req.password}`)
            try {
                var authenticationDetails = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails({
                    Username: req.emailAddress,
                    Password: req.password
                });
                var userData = {
                    Username: req.emailAddress,
                    Pool: this.userPool
                };
                this.cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser(userData);
                await this.authenticateUser(this.cognitoUser, authenticationDetails).then(value=> {
                    resolve(value)
                }).catch(error => {
                    console.log(`This is the login error catch----> ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                });
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(`I entered into the catch of try block ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                reject(error);
            }
        });
    }
```

And this is my authenticate method:

```js
    private async authenticateUser(cognitoUser: AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser, authenticationDetails: AmazonCognitoIdentity.AuthenticationDetails) {
        console.log(`Inside authenticate user`);
        console.log(`This is the cognitoUser in the auth function -----> ${JSON.stringify(cognitoUser)} and tehse are the authentication details-----> ${JSON.stringify(authenticationDetails)}`)
        return new Promise<any>(async (resolve, reject) => {
            try{
                console.log(`Trying man!.....`); //<-- This gets logged . But then directly goesd to the catch block
                await cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, { //<--- The control doesn't enter this function. It directly flows to the catch block of try
                    onSuccess: (result) => {
                        console.log(`This is the success result ----> ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
                        resolve(result)
                    },
                    onFailure: (error) => {
                        console.log(`This is the error being returned in onFailure ----> ${JSON.stringify(error)}`)
                        resolve(error)
                    }
                })
            }
            catch(error){
                console.log(`This is the error from authenticate try catch block ${JSON.stringify(error)}`);
                reject(error);
            }
            
        })

    }
```

Comment: Provide `JSON.stringify(error)` value.

Comment: I get null. But I just fixed that issue, and stuck with another. THe solution was here https://github.com/aws-amplify/amplify-js/issues/7098#issuecomment-720590736